# How do I generate a normal looking URL for a delete User with Devise, rather than a URL with a format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

On the settings page of the user account, I want to add a cancel button. The issue I keep having is that the normal things keep creating a URL that has a `.format`.

This is what I do in my view:

```
<%= link_to "Cancel my account", cancel_user_account_path(resource), data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to cancel your account? All of your memories WILL be lost!" }, method: :delete, class: "btn left" %>
```

**Routes**

```
delete "cancel", to: "users#destroy", as: :cancel_user_account
```

Which generates this in my `rake routes`:

```
cancel_user_account_path    DELETE  /cancel(.:format)   users#destroy
```

This is what my `User#Destroy` looks like:

```
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.destroy
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "You have successfully cancelled your account."
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end    
  end
```

That's normal.

But that keeps generating this URL: `http://localhost:3000/cancel.148`

Which generates this error when clicked:

```
Started DELETE "/cancel.148" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-21 00:30:02 -0500
Processing by UsersController#destroy as 
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 148  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  FamilyTree Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "family_trees".* FROM "family_trees"  WHERE "family_trees"."user_id" = 148 LIMIT 1
  Node Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."family_tree_id" IN (150)
  Role Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 148]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 23ms (ActiveRecord: 4.6ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find User without an ID:
```

In my error page, I can check the params...and this is what it is sending with the request:

```
Request parameters  
{"_method"=>"delete", "action"=>"destroy", "controller"=>"users", "format"=>"148"}
```

I have no idea how to get it to just generate `/cancel/148`.

I tried many permutations of the routes, including putting it within the `devise_for :user` block like so:

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get "settings", to: "devise/registrations#edit"
    delete "logout", to: "devise/sessions#destroy"
    delete "cancel", to: "users#destroy", as: :cancel_user_account
  end
```

I even tried using the other route that devise seems to have generated:

```
edit_user_registration_path GET /users/edit(.:format)   registrations#edit
                            PATCH   /users(.:format)    registrations#update
                            PUT /users(.:format)    registrations#update
                            DELETE  /users(.:format)    registrations#destroy
```

But even that still generates a weird path: `http://localhost:3000/users/edit.148`,  which generates a similar error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /users/edit.148
Couldn't find User with 'id'=edit
```

These are the params:

```
Request parameters  
{"_method"=>"delete", "action"=>"destroy", "controller"=>"users", "id"=>"edit", "format"=>"148"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defined route is not correct.

It would be:

```
delete "/users/:id/cancel", to: "users#destroy", as: :cancel_user_account
```

Actually, this is shorter but enough (ensure it doesn't conflict with other routes)

```
delete "/users/:id", to: "users#destroy", as: :cancel_user_account
```

Comment: Ahh perfect. This is exactly what I was missing. The `:id` in the route. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are sending resource as input to `cancel_user_account_path`, which only has a format parameter, so rails guesses that you mean the resource to map to format. There are two things you can do:

1- You can explicitly tell rails what the input should map to:

```
cancel_user_account_path(id: resource) #=> http://localhost:3000/cancel?id: 148
```

2- You can add id to your route, so that rails would map the first input to it:

```
delete "cancel/:id", to: "users#destroy", as: :cancel_user_account #=> http://localhost:3000/cancel/148
```

**BUT**, both of the above are dangerous to do in a production environment. As long as you are expecting user id as input, anybody can cancel any user's account! It is much safer to actually not pass/expect any input ids and change your controller action to use the `current_user`:

```
def destroy
    if current_user.destroy
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "You have successfully cancelled your account."
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end    
end
```

Comment: Well, I am using CanCanCan for authorization and that controller is locked down. So it checks to see if the current_user has the required permission per my `ability.rb` to delete that user record and then it does it accordingly. So it is similar to what you suggest.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how I might test this properly, to make sure it is working? I can't just go visit a URL. How do I send a `:delete` to a specific URL manually?

Comment: Depends on what framework you are using for testing. If it is rspec, you can use the `delete` method available in controller tests. Cucumber tests will be able to use the link (BTW a button might be better, semantically we reserve links for actions that are not dangerous) as long as they are using a javascript enabled driver. For non javascript drivers, you would need to create another route with get (only in cucumber env) for the links to work. I am not sure if I understood your question correctly though. Please feel free to elaborate

Comment: I actually meant testing it by hand, but you raise a good point about just writing an automated test. If I wanted to do it by hand, ideas?

Comment: Can't you create dummy accounts and see if you can cancel them manually?